# Adding a close button to the modal view that is partially off the view

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiview, modal-dialog

I am trying to add a "X" button to the top of the modal view so if the user presses that it closes the modal view.  I looked at the solution proposed here [how to add close button to modal view corner which is presented in UIModalPresentationPageSheet?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15983731/how-to-add-close-button-to-modal-view-corner-which-is-presented-in-uimodalpresen)

[image: modal view with 'x' button]

But I have two follow up questions here as i am fairly new to ios programming

1. The solution proposed in the above page does not seem to work for me. I tried it with a normal button first in the viewDidLoad of the modal VC and I am seeing it appear only within the bounds of modal view and not outside as I want.

   ```
   UIView *buttonView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 100, 50)];
   buttonView.backgroundColor = [UIColor brownColor];
   CGRect buttonFrame = CGRectMake( 0, 0, 100, 50 );
   UIButton *button = [[UIButton alloc] initWithFrame: buttonFrame];
   [button setTitle: @"Close" forState: UIControlStateNormal];
   [button setTitleColor: [UIColor redColor] forState: UIControlStateNormal];
   [button addTarget:self
               action:@selector(closeButtonPressed)
     forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
   [buttonView addSubview: button];


   CGRect parentView = self.view.superview.frame;
   CGRect currentView = self.view.frame;
   CGRect buttonViewFrame = buttonView.frame;
   buttonViewFrame.origin = CGPointMake(parentView.origin.x -      buttonViewFrame.size.width/2.0f, parentView.origin.y - buttonViewFrame.size.height/2.0f);

   [buttonView setFrame:buttonViewFrame];
   [self.view addSubview:buttonView];
   ```

what I am seeing is [image: clipped image]

2. How do I draw the "X" button do I use CGRect to draw it our or instead of adding a button in the above example should I just add a image with the "X" in it as the subview?

thanks in advance for the help

Comment: Is your modal view controller clipping its subviews?  If you're using storyboards, confirm that the "Clip Subviews" checkbox is UNCHECKED.  If you're doing the modal viewController programmatically, set the modal viewController's `clipsToBounds` property to NO.  Give it a try.

Comment: the modal view is a table view controller and it was checked and i unchecked it and I am still seeing the same result.. I updated the originalpost with the image of what i am seeing even after the unchecking the box

Answer (score 1):

do like this, hope helps u :)

```
    //adding button to your view 
    UIView *aView = [[UIView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(100, 200, 300, 350)];
    aView.backgroundColor = [UIColor blueColor];
    aView.tag = 100;
   [self.view addSubview:aView];

   UIButton *aButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
   [aButton setTitle:@"CLOSE" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
   [aButton addTarget:self action:@selector(tapped:)     forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
   aButton.frame = CGRectMake(aView.bounds.origin.x, aView.bounds.origin.y, 80, 30);// adjust with respect to bounds 
   aButton.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];
   [aView addSubview:aButton];
   [aView release];     //i am doing without ARC
```

Answer (score 0):

The other option is to create a larger view and put your UITableView within this, along with your close button. The close button can then be at position (0,0) and the UITableView can start at (25,25).
This prevents complications - I have seen clipped views fail to recognise the touch outside of the main view, so your 50x50 button only has a touch area of 25x25.